# making higher level abstraction components with spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to find a way to create higher level abstraction components out of currently available spring integration EIP components. For example I would like to replace several constructs:

```
<int:gateway id="inMemoryPopulator"
           default-request-channel="channel"
           service-interface="com.xyz.gateway.InMemoryPopulator"/>

<!-- dispatching to JMS -->

<int:gateway id="jmsPopulator"
           default-request-channel="dispatchChannel"
           service-interface="com.xyz.gateway.JMSPopulator"/>

<int:channel id="dispatchChannel"/>

<int:chain input-channel="dispatchChannel">
<int:header-enricher ref="queueNameEnricher"
                     method="populateQueueName"/>
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="jmsOut"
                                  destination-expression="headers.targetQueueName"/>
</int:chain>
```

with something like:

```
<int:chain input-channel="channel">
  <int:header-enricher ref="queueNameEnricher"
                       method="populateQueueName"/>
  <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter-fast id="fastJmsOut"
                                             number-workers="10"                     
                                             internal-queue-size="1000"
                                             destination-expression="headers.targetQueueName"/>
</int:chain>
```

To use an analogy, if spring integration EIP components are like basic electronic components (transistors, capacitors, resistors, diodes, etc.) I'd like to create the equivalent of integrated circuits (adders, amplifiers, etc.).

That way, over time, systems of increasing complexity can be created with ease. Such systems would be easier to test and maintain. So is something like this possible? And if so how? If not, do people think this would be a good thing to have available?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you mean; your second snippet is just like the chain in your first snippet, with just a couple more attributes on the outbound adapter.

See [spring-integration-flow](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-flow) which is an extension that provides a mechanism to configure subflows that can be invoked as "services" from other flows.

Comment: The difference is that the second snippet encapsulates and 'hides' everything in a single construct. Notice the name (outbound-channel-adapter-fast) to distinguish it from the regular one (outbound-channel-adapter). If I wanted to build such a construct, how would I do it? Thanks for the pointer to spring-integration-flow. Will look at that to see if I can use it.